# How can I wrap a floated span underneath another floated span, within a floated span [diagram included]?

Tags: css, css-float, word-wrap

I have a newsfeed/chat box. Each entry contains two spans: #user and #message.  I would like #user to float left, and #message to float left upon it.  If #message causes the row to exceed the container width, #message should wrap below #user, as shown in the diagram below.

By default #message jumps completely beneath #user if it does not fit on the same row.
I have tried whitespace:nowrap on each element but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Help?

[image: diagram]

Comment: You want the borders like this too?

Comment: Borders do not need to be visible like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if both elements are `display:inline` this should solve the problem of #message going completely beneath #user. No need to float anything.

Demo (not much to see): http://jsfiddle.net/YK3R9/

Feel free to use semantic markup instead of spans and divs, I just used them for the demo.

If you need the border on message to display the way it is in your drawing, just say so. I wasn't sure if it was a visual aid or the way you actually want it rendered. Simply adding the border to the element looks a bit weird when the message spans multiple lines, so we might need a helper span.

EDIT: Saw your note that borders don't matter.

**Moral of the story:** No need for `float` here.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was something basic, since no one else seemed to have this issue.  Just had to add float:none to #message.

Comment: Yeah, I hesitated quite a bit before posting because I though this was a little too easy. Glad you got it figured out and hopefully relieved of some "floatitis" :)